# Wicket: how to create ExternalLink with <a href="..." target="_blank">

Tags: java, wicket

Within a table cell, I have to create a Wicket `ExternalLink` that shows the response in a new browser tab.
I've used this code (Wicket 7.9):

```
columns.add(new AbstractColumn<WebService, String>(Model.of(" "))
{
    @Override
    public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<WebService>> cellItem, String componentId,
            IModel<WebService> serviceModel)
    {
        WebService ows = serviceModel.getObject();
        String url = "http://www.geodata.com/map?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities";
        ExternalLink capabilitiesLink =
                new ExternalLink(componentId, Model.of(url), Model.of("Caps"))
                {
                    @Override
                    protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag)
                    {
                        super.onComponentTag(tag);
                        tag.put("target", "_blank");
                    }
                };
        cellItem.add(capabilitiesLink);
    }
});
```

But Wicket renders this:
`<div onclick="window.location.href='http://www.geodata.com/maps?service=WFS&amp;request=GetCapabilities';return false;" target="_blank">Caps</div>`

This doesn't open a new tab.

The tables HTML markup is generated by Wicket, so I can't insert
`<td><a wicket:id="link" href="..."></a></td>` in the corresponding markup.

**How can I force Wicket to render `<a href=" ... " target="_blank">Caps</a>` ?**

Alternatively, how can I create a new browser tab when I can't avoid using `onClick` (Javascript) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem by creating an extension of Wickets `Panel` with this simple markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:wicket="http://wicket.apache.org">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
<wicket:panel>
    <a wicket:id="link"></a>
</wicket:panel>
</body>
</html>
```

Because of `<a wicket:id="link">` Wicket doesn't create Javascript for the link.

Corresponding Java:

```
public class LinkTargetBlankPanel extends Panel
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -6527814402202345257L;

    public LinkTargetBlankPanel(String id, String url, String label)
    {
        super(id);
        add(new ExternalLink("link", url, label)
        {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = -8010560272317354356L;

            @Override
            protected void onComponentTag(ComponentTag tag)
            {
                super.onComponentTag(tag);
                tag.put("target", "_blank");
            }
        });
    }
}
```

And in the code that creates the table column:

```
columns.add(new AbstractColumn<WebService, String>(Model.of(" "))
{
    @Override
    public void populateItem(Item<ICellPopulator<WebService>> cellItem, String componentId,
            IModel<WebService> serviceModel)
    {
        String url = "http://www.geodata.com/map?service=WMS&request=GetCapabilities";
        cellItem.add(new LinkTargetBlankPanel("link", url, "GetCapabilities"));
    }
});
```

Comment: The difference is that in your question you use a `div` instead of `a`. That's why Wicket uses JavaScript. Also the `target` attribute could be in the markup

Comment: @martin-g - the link is placed within a `BootstrapDataTable`. Is there a way to create `<a href="...">` in my implementation of `populateItem` without using a `Panel` ?

Comment: I just pointed out why your first attempt was failing. May be someone will face the same in the future. Using a Fragment is a lighter solution. Also it is possible to do it by only dealing with `onBeforeRender`, `onComponentTag` and `onAfterRender` but it is questionable whether it will be better than Fragment/Panel.

Answer (score 0):

java:

```
ExternalLink("link", new PropertyModel<>(model, "url"))
```

html :

```
<td><a target="_blank" wicket:id="link">Open</a></td>
```